# Erro Invalid/Unknown/Unsupported format

Tags: c#

Eu tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
new PrintPDF(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Comprovante"]);
```

Que está declaro na *app.config*:

```
<add key="Comprovante" value="C:\Client\Resp\Comprovante.txt" />
```

Que vai até o método `PrintPDF`, porém quando chega na linha `doc.LoadFromFile(arquivo)` me retornando o erro:

> Invalid/Unknown/Unsupported format

Porém eu não sei o que está causando essa *exception*

Método:

```
public PrintPDF(string arquivo)
        {
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            doc.LoadFromFile(arquivo);

            //Use the default printer to print all the pages 
            //doc.PrintDocument.Print(); 

            //Set the printer and select the pages you want to print 

            PrintDialog dialogPrint = new PrintDialog
            {
                AllowPrintToFile = true,
                AllowSomePages = true
            };
            dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MinimumPage = 1;
            dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MaximumPage = doc.Pages.Count;
            dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
            dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage = doc.Pages.Count;

            if (dialogPrint.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the start page to print 
                doc.PrintFromPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage;
                //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the final page to print 
                doc.PrintToPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage;
                //Set the name of the printer which is to print the PDF 
                doc.PrinterName = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

                PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument;
                dialogPrint.Document = printDoc;

                printDoc.Print();


               }
```

Comment: Você provavelmente não esta passando o formato do arquivo de saida. Mas não conhecimento desse método pra te dizer como específicar esse formato no código.

Comment: O método quer um caminho para carregar um pdf, e você esta passando um txt, simples.